# Filtering for two identical consecutive entries in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

Imagine a snippet of the follow data frame:

```
       ID        ActivityName     Time         Type    Shape 
1       1             Request    0.000       Type_1      767           
2       1             Request  600.000       Type_1      767           
3       1               Start  600.000       Type_1     1376           
4       1               Start  600.000       Type_1     1376           
5       1 Schedule Activities  600.000       Type_1       15           
6       1 Schedule Activities 2062.295       Type_1       15
```

What I'm trying to do is to create two new columns based on the repeating entries in `ActivityName`.

Specifically, I want to combine two subsequent rows for the same activity into one row with a start and
complete timestamp (from `Time`, in seconds.)

Given that *not all* entries in `ActivityName` have a matching second entry (however, max two consecutive entries are identical), I would also like to *delete* such "single-standing" rows.

P.s. Although not seen in the data frame snippet, all levels of ActivityName occur *repeatedly*, whether in consecutive-identical or in single fashion.

Any ideas for how to go about this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that `ID` is a variable that indicates which entries from `ActivityName` should be grouped, this should work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  #Group by ID and ActivityName
  group_by(ID, ActivityName) %>%
  #Stay only with entries with more than 1 row
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  #Put the min value of Time as Start and the max value as Timestamp 
  summarize (Start = min(Time),
             Timestamp = max(Time))
```

Comment: If there were not consecutive matching entries this would still include them, not sure if that's a problem for @Alex

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Indeed, as Sarah mentions, the solution doesn't seem to delete single-standing entries from the "ActivityName" column though, i.e. entries that are not followed by an identical one. I should also have clarified that the entries in ActivityName repeat themselves, as in there being numerous consecutive or single instances of 'Request', 'Start' etc. What I want is to keep all the entries that come first in one column and move their consecutive entry into a corresponding second column (again, without single-standing entries). Sorry for not being able to explain it in simpler terms

Comment: Ok, then I think something like this should work: `df$Timestamp<-sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  ifelse(df$ActivityName[i] == df$ActivityName[i+1], df$Time[i+1], NA)
})
df[!is.na(df$Timestamp),]`.